# Use Jython Subprocess to send commands to bash shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

I need to send a number of **subsequent** commands to **one** bash shell in a Jython engine.
Executing commands 1 by 1, with os.system(s) or subsystem.call(s, ...) does not work as a new shell is created every time.

I hope someone has an idea .... following 3 tests are not a sufficient slution.

```
Sample Commands : <br>
cd /home/xxx/dir1/dir2<br>
pwd<br>
cd ..<br>
pwd
```

In this first test, the commands are executed, but the output is only retrieved at the end.

```
def testRun1():
   # Actual Output
   #     run 0
   #     run 1
   #     run 2
   #     /home/usr/dir1/dir2
   #     /home/usr/dir1
   #     /home/usr
   print 'All output is shown at the end...'
   proc = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash',
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           )
   for i in range(3):
       print 'run ' + str(i)
       proc.stdin.write('pwd\n')
       proc.stdin.write('cd ..\n')
   output = proc.communicate()[0]
   print output
```

Whereas the 'desired output' is

```
 #     run 0
 #     /home/usr/dir1/dir2
 #     run 1
 #     /home/usr/dir1
 #     run 2
 #     /home/usr
```

This second tryout delivers what we want, but the output is only shown when jython script is interrupted.

```
def testRun2():
   # Weird : it is what we want, but all output is blocked until CTRL-C is   pressed
   #     run 0
   #     /home/usr/dir1/dir2
   #     run 1
   #     /home/usr/dir1
   #     run 2
   #     /home/usr
   proc = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash',
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           )
   for i in range(3):
       print 'run ' + str(i)
       proc.stdin.write('pwd\n')
       proc.stdin.write('cd ..\n')
       print 'start to print output'
       for line in proc.stdout:
           print(line.decode("utf-8"))
       print_remaining(proc.stdout)
       print 'printed output'
```

This last tryout crashes in the second run because a stream was closed.

```
def testRun3():
   # This fails with error
   #  ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
   proc = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash',
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           )
   for i in range(3):
       print 'run ' + str(i)
       proc.stdin.write('pwd\n')
       proc.stdin.write('cd ..\n')
       output = proc.communicate()[0]
       print output
```

Comment: 1.  Why not write a shell script and run that?  2.  What on earth are you doing using the shell anyway?  What can bash do that python/jython cannot?

Answer (score 0):

The troubles you're having are only partially to do with `subprocess`.  Pipes are fundamentally the wrong IPC mechanism for this job.  To put an interactive command interpreter under scripted control, what you *want* is a [pseudoterminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminals.html), and even then it's not as simple as reading and writing.

The Python standard library doesn't have any built-in modules that do pseudoterminal handling for you, unless they've added something very recently that I'm not aware of.  However, the third-party package  [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can do it, and it's geared for exactly the thing you are trying to do.

Using the basic pexpect API:

```
import pexpect

def testRun4():
   proc = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
   for i in range(3):
       proc.expect(":^[^$#]*[$#] *")
       print("run", i)
       proc.sendline("pwd")
       proc.expect("^[^$#]*[$#] *")
       print(proc.before)
       proc.sendline("cd ..")
```

With [`pexpect.replwrap`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/replwrap.html), it's a little more involved to set up but then the loop is tidier:

```
def testRun5():
    proc = pexpect.replwrap.REPLWrapper(
        "/bin/bash",
        orig_prompt="^[^$#]*[$#] *",
        prompt_change="PS1='{}'; PS2='{}'")

    for i in range(3):
        print("run", i)
        print(proc.run_command("pwd"))
        proc.run_command("cd ..")
```

Comment: Then I need to review how I can install pexpect. Currently I am using thinclient.sh with a jython.jar, and no full python (pip) installation....
I will dive deeper

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you with the "proper" way to install add-on modules to Jython, but `pexpect` doesn't have any compiled components, so in the worst case you could just copy it into your application.